# MuleSoft - Quartz set repeatInterval from property file

Tags: mule, mule-studio

My simple question is how to set quartz repeatInterval variable from a property file?
I try with:

```
        <quartz:inbound-endpoint repeatInterval="#[Integer.parseInt(message.inboundProperties['SCHEDULE_FREQUENCY'])]" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="quartzConnector_vm" doc:name="Event_generator" jobName="chicken">
```

but doesn't work. I made many tries but I always get the same message: "Value must be an integer or a Mule espression".
Actually I managed to let only integer values work.
Any clue on this?
Thanks

Comment: I found as a workaround to parameterize the cronExpression, which is a String, instead of the repeatInterval.

Comment: Can you close/delete this question then?

Comment: or put your solution in there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found as a workaround to parameterize the cronExpression, which is a String, instead of the repeatInterval.